# two autocompletes at one page

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete. It actually works, but when I tried to put another one below on the same website, it shows me white spaces instead of results. I have already tried to copy the script, but changing its names, etc but it still doesnt work. What i found is that only the first autocomplete form always works only. I am working on this since like 2 weeks, checked all the topics and cant figure it out. Any help please?

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <input type="text" name="searchFriends" class="searchFriends" placeholder="search friends">
</div>

<style>
    .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    try {
        $(".searchFriends").autocomplete({
            source:    "/searchFriends",
            minLength: 3,
            select:    function(event, ui) { 
                    if(ui.item.type=="group")
                        window.location.href = "/group/" + ui.item.id;
                    else
                        window.location.href = "/u/" + ui.item.login;
                }
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $(
                    "<li style='clear:both;'><img src='" + item.avatar + "' style='margin-right:2px;float:left;max-height:30px;max-width:30px;'/>"
                ).append("<a>" + item.login + "<br>" + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name + "</a>"
                ).appendTo(ul);
        };
    } catch(exc) {
        console.log(exc);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please edit your question and correct the indentation of your code, it's difficult to read in its current state.

Comment: @AndyDavies I just have used netbeans to make it clear. Hope it is better now

Comment: Not really but I'll sort it out...

Comment: @AndyDavies I am not very experienced, sorry about that

Comment: Can you post all code of this page?